# Updating a Debezium MySQL connector with table whitelist option

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using the Debezium (0.7.5) MySQL connector and I'm trying to understand what is the best approach if I want to update this configuration with the option `table.whitelist`.

Let's say I create a connector, something like this:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://debezium-host/connectors/ -d '
{
  "name": "MyConnector",
  "config": {
      "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
      "connect.timeout.ms": "60000",
      "tasks.max": "1",
      "database.hostname": "myhost",
      "database.port": "3306",
      "database.user": "***",
      "database.password": "***",
      "database.server.id": "3227197",
      "database.server.name": "MyServer",
      "database.whitelist": "myDb",
      "table.whitelist": "myDb.table1,myDb.table2",
      "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kb0:9092,kb1:9092,kb2:9092",
      "database.history.kafka.topic": "MyConnectorHistoryTopic",
      "max.batch.size": "1024",
      "snapshot.mode": "initial",
      "decimal.handling.mode": "double"
    }
}'
```

After some time (2 weeks), I need to add a new table (`myDb.table3`) to this `table.whitelist` option (and this table is an old one, it was created before the connector)

What I tried was:

- Pause the connector.
- Deleted the history topic (maybe this was the problem?).
- Updated the config via API update config endpoint.
- Resume the connector.

Update command via API:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" -H  "Content-Type:application/json" https://kafka-connect-host/connectors/MyConnector/config/ -d '
{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "connect.timeout.ms": "60000",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "database.hostname": "myhost",
  "database.port": "3306",
  "database.user": "***",
  "database.password": "***",
  "database.server.id": "3227197",
  "database.server.name": "MyServer",
  "database.whitelist": "myDb",
  "table.whitelist": "myDb.table1,myDb.table2,myDb.table3",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kb0:9092,kb1:9092,kb2:9092",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "MyConnectorHistoryTopic",
  "max.batch.size": "1024",
  "snapshot.mode": "schema_only",
  "decimal.handling.mode": "double"
}'
```

But it didn't work and maybe this isn't the best approach at all. 
In other connectors I'm not using the option `table.whitelist`, so when I needed to listen na new table, I didn't have this problem.

My last option, I think would be delete this connector and create another one with this new configuration also listening the new table (`myDb.table3`). The problem is if I want the initial data from `myDb.table3` I would have to create with the snapshot `initial` but I don't wanna to generate all the messages from the snapshot from the other tables `myDb.table1,myDb.table2`.

Comment: You could post an entirely new config rather than update the existing one

Comment: @cricket_007 You mean deleting the existing connector and creating a new one? Or just creating another connector with a different name?

Comment: You could do either, I guess, but deleting anything would affect the running connectors

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think OP is looking for a Production-system solution offering consistency, what you suggested sounds very risky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes to the whitelist/blacklist config are not yet supported at this point. This is currently being worked on (see [DBZ-175](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/DBZ/issues/DBZ-175)), and we hope to have preview support for this in one of the next releases. There's a [pending PR](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/pull/485) for this, which needs a bit more work, though.

Until this has been implemented, your best option is to set up a new instance of the connector which *only* captures the additional tables you're interested in. This comes at the price of running two connectors (which both will maintain a binlog reader session), but it does the trick as long as you don't need to change your filter config too often.

Comment: Thanks, @Gunnar. I did what you suggested. 
Now, I'm planning to migrate from Debezium 7.5 to 9 to avoid this problem.

Comment: @japoneizo have you got you problem solution with new version?. If yes then please send me debezium exact version you are using.

Comment: @japoneizo currently on which version are you using? If you are on 0.10, then well and good it's working fine(make sure this configuration ```binlog_row_image=full```). If  0.9.2.Final, How did you achieve?

Comment: is this issue also happen with latest version of DBZ? like ver 1.1?

Comment: is it still an issue?

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of Debezium Server, you can add the following config

```
debezium.snapshot.new.tables=parallel
```

In case If you are using Debezium, you can try this config value

```
snapshot.new.tables=parallel
```

Note: Debeziyum Server is the one that supports Kinesis, Google Pub sub, and Apache Pulsar. I am using that and its configuration is a bit different. I had to prepend "debezium" before each item

Once this configuration is added, any addition to tables.whitelist, For these additional tables Debezium will create snapshots.

I cannot point you to the documentation but I went through their code in GitHub and also I tried it practically which worked for me.
Here is the link to the MySqlConnector code

https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/master/debezium-connector-mysql/src/main/java/io/debezium/connector/mysql/MySqlConnectorConfig.java

There search for
Field.create("snapshot.new.tables")

Personally, I feel like Debezium has a lot of things but documentation is scattered.

Comment: Hey Pavan, could you post a link to the documentation about the snapshot.new.tables config please? I can't find it on the docs site

Comment: Hi @MarkNS, I cannot point you to the documentation but I went through their code in github and also I tried it practically which worked for me.
Here is the link to MySqlConnector code 

https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/master/debezium-connector-mysql/src/main/java/io/debezium/connector/mysql/MySqlConnectorConfig.java

There search for 
Field.create("snapshot.new.tables")

Personally, I feel like Debezium has a lot of things but documentation is scattered.

Comment: with debezium-connector-mysql-1.8.1.Final-plugin It's not working , what version are your using ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

i am have the same problem and solve with a signal table to debezium. Its work that way, you have to create a table to send to debezium commands in your datatable.

```
CREATE TABLE public.debezium_signal (id VARCHAR(42) PRIMARY KEY, type VARCHAR(32)  NULL, data VARCHAR(2048)  NULL);
```

and set in your configuration do debzium a tag `"signal.data.collection": "public.debezium_signal"`

after that you can send commands with insert in that table:

```
INSERT INTO debezium_signal (id, type, data)
VALUES(gen_random_uuid(),'execute-snapshot','{"data-collections": "myDb.table3"]}');
```

in my case i have to add de table signal in table.include.list and the columns in column.include.list as well.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/configuration/signalling.html